# fetch timezone and covert to utc

Tags: python-3.x

I have a requirement which has input as 2020-03-21T11:23:50-05:00, and output should be two different variables

```html
covertedutc : 2020-03-21 16:23:50
timezone : -05:00
```

i have tried without timezone in input variable and below is snippet

```html
import datetime
import pytz

timestring = "2020-03-21T11:23:50"

# Create datetime object
d = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestring, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
print(d.strftime("%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S"))
```

Comment: i wasn't able to find a solution on how to handle with the timezone as input variable and get the desired output.

Comment: What does T stand for? And which are the two variables?

Comment: Ideally, The T doesn’t really stand for anything. It is just the separator that the ISO 8601 combined date-time format requires.

Comment: input variable : 2020-03-21T11:23:50-05:00 ,                                                    
expected out put :                                                                                                       
 1) covertedutc : 2020-03-21 16:23:50
 2)  timezone : -05:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

variable='2020-03-21T11:23:50-05:00'
variable = " ".join(variable.split("T")) #eliminating the  "T"

converted = datetime.strptime(variable[:19], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + timedelta(hours=5)

print(f'covertedutc {converted}')
print(f'timezone {variable[19:]}')
```

Output:

```
covertedutc 2020-03-21 16:23:50
timezone -05:00
```